# Assets are not saved in dynamically generated folders

Tags: assets

I setup an Assets field called Images. My Default Upload Location is set as `{parent.uri}/{slug}`

My File System Path for that folder is `img/`

The directory structure that is generated is correct and in this format: `img/artists/artist_name/category_name/project_name`

But the images are being saved in the root `img/` directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: Assuming this field lives in a structured section, did you add it to the "My Default Upload Location" setting, which only applies to files drag-and-dropped onto the field?  Or did you check the "Restrict uploads to a single folder" setting and add it to the "Upload Location" setting?  The latter is the one you probably want to do.

Comment: Can you add what the solution you ended up using as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the images to upload into correct folders by switching Image field to "Restrict uploads to a single folder" option. I also had to fix the File System Path in Settings>Assets>Asset Sources to the full file system path.

Comment: If you got it to work, you can accept your own answer – then others with the same problem can see there is a solution to find here :)